# How to add CSS class field in Custom Taxonomy?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

This is my code for custom taxonomy

```
register_taxonomy(
        'job_location',
        'noo_job',
        array(
            'labels'       => array(
                'name'          => __( 'Job Location', 'noo' ),
                'add_new_item'  => __( 'Add New Job Location', 'noo' ),
                'new_item_name' => __( 'New Job Location', 'noo' )
            ),
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'query_var'    => true,
            'rewrite'      => array( 'slug' => _x( 'job-location', 'slug', 'noo' ) )
        ) );
```

I want to add a CSS class field here so that I can assign any CSS class here.

Comment: What do you what to do with css class? In registration custom post you can not add any stuff like this. You can add class in css archve or single template of custom post.

Comment: I want to hide few taxonomies in a specific page. This is clients weired requirement. Please let me know how can I add a class option over their.